# DBF/FoxPro Connection with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object, foxpro, dbf

i want to make a connection with a DBF file through VBA, i have installed all the drivers but i get this error message every time i try to run it

> Object variable not set (Error 91)

```
Sub Teste()

Dim dbConn As OLEDBConnection

dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" & "G:\Registros_Oficiais\Contabilidade\2022_01\ARREIDEN.DBF" & ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"

dbConn.Open
    
End Sub
```

Can someone help me? What am i missing?

Comment: `dbConn` is `Nothing` until you actually `Set` it to a new (or existing) connection.

Comment: I tried this one before Set dbConn = New OLEDBConnection but VBA Getting Compile Error: Invalid use of new keyword

Comment: Right, because that's not how you add a connection.

Comment: Also, an `OLEDBConnection` is a workbook connection and has no `.Open` method. You may be looking for an `ADODB.Connection`?

Comment: Hmm i will look for this one  ADODB that fit with dbf files, thank you

Comment: Take a look at this link with connection strings examples:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string needs to point to the PATH where the data resides, not the specific table.  So if your connection is to

```
"G:\Registros_Oficiais\Contabilidade\2022_01"
```

Your queries will just need to reference the tables such as

```
select * from SomeTable where...
```